# ClickOnce Deployment - File Association not Registering

Tags: c#, file, deployment, clickonce, associations

So here's a brief summary of the problem:

**Summary:**

> I set fileAssociations of my ClickOnce applications, however, they are **not registering** when I **run/update** my program *(as in, the .bvr files I am trying to associate have no icon and I can't double-click them to start my application)*.

**Extra Info:**

I first tried going to Properties -> Publish -> Options -> File Associations and setting my associations from there. After that failed attempt, I tried setting it directly in app.manifest:

```
<fileAssociation
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1"
extension=".bvr"
description="Behavior File"
progid="GGS.Behavior"
defaultIcon="bvrico.ico"
/>
```

I've read so many articles about this that I am starting to get frustrated. Some information:

1. I've set it to a full-trust application (Under security -> Enable ClickOnce security settings -> This is a full trust application)
2. I am using .NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010
3. Enable "offline" mode

I also handle the data passed through AppDomain, but I doubt that really changes anything.

I was wondering maybe file associations are only set on install.

Anyways, I would really appreciate some insight on this problem. I would really like file associations in my project.

Thanks everyone in advance.

PS:
Tested on Windows XP and Windows 7.

Edit: I also have posted this on Microsoft, btw.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/d610cd55-f3c7-4775-a417-251261832200

If anyone would like to post an answer on there as well. I really can't figure this one out. :D

Comment: Isnt there some command line to register file association. Simply re-register it by starting a little command line on app start and you should be good to go. http://commandwindows.com/assoc.htm

Comment: File associations don't seem to only be set on install - I updated a test application that had no associations set with new settings for adding file associations and the application started fine when double clicking the associated file.

Answer (score 6):

If the filetype you are trying to register has previously been registered with another program (such as notepad), or even opened in notepad, then the only way ive found to get it working is to delete from the registry the filetype in 2 locations, and then reboot.  After that publish an update for your app, and if its that sort of problem your in good shape.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bvr

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bvr

Reboot

Publish an update to your app.

Comment: What of it is of the other type? The answer is incomplete!

Comment: I simply deleted the file extension at the above registry keys, uninstalled the program, re-installed the program and it worked.  In my situation, most likely another program had been associated with the file extension.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the following item didn't appear in *Open With...* file options - **Clickonce Application Deployment Support Library** with question mark icon? Try setting it as a default.

I had the same problem as yours, but I noticed this strange option appears after I install my application. After so much trying and googling I tried a simple thing - agreed to make this **Clickonce Application Deployment Support Library** a default for desired file type. And ta da! The file's icon turned into my app icon and it launched my app. I guess the thing was my desired file type was already associated with **Notepad**, so ClickOnce refused to override this setting.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get this to work after a ClickOnce deployment is to add/update several registry entries in code. See below.

It's been 8 years, and even in the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 with Windows 10, **the file association settings in ClickOnce deployments still don't work**. I suspect this is a Windows version issue, as Microsoft seems to change how file associations are stored in the registry with every new version of Windows. But regardless, Visual Studio and ClickOnce should ***work*** for the current Windows release. And it does not.

After completing a clean install of my ClickOnce app, I found this one registry entry for my file extension:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.xxxxxx
```

And it added this registry entry for the ProgID:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xxxxxxxxxxx
```

But it did not add a reference from the file extension to the ProgID.

These two entries do nothing in Windows 10. It does not show the icon, does not open the ClickOnce app when you open the file with that extension, and does not show any ClickOnce option in the Open With lists (as a commenter suggested). Note that the registry entry above was created by the deployment but contains no reference to the ClickOnce application or the ProgID that was set up in the ClickOnce properties. In fact, the only application referenced in that file extension registry entry is to "OpenWith.exe".

#### Solution

After spending 2 days researching this issue and piecing together various ideas, the solution below is the only one I found that works. Simply execute SetAssociation() every time your app starts (or at least immediately after an install/upgrade), and it will solve the file association problem in all versions of Windows.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class FileAssociations
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
        private static extern int SHChangeNotify(int eventId, int flags, IntPtr item1, IntPtr item2);

        private const int SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED = 0x8000000;
        private const int SHCNF_FLUSH = 0x1000;

        public static bool SetAssociation(string extension, string progId, string fileTypeDescription, string applicationFilePath)
        {
            bool madeChanges = false;
            madeChanges |= SetKeyDefaultValue(@"Software\Classes\" + extension, progId);
            madeChanges |= SetKeyDefaultValue(@"Software\Classes\" + progId, fileTypeDescription);
            madeChanges |= SetKeyDefaultValue($@"Software\Classes\{progId}\shell\open\command", "\"" + applicationFilePath + "\" \"%1\"");
            return madeChanges;
        }

        private static bool SetKeyDefaultValue(string keyPath, string value)
        {
            using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(keyPath))
            {
                if (key.GetValue(null) as string != value)
                {
                    key.SetValue(null, value);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then execute this on program start. The first item in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() contains the full path to your exe:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
FileAssociations.SetAssociation(FileExtension, ProgID, FileExtensionDescription, args[0]);
```

The only problem I found with this approach is if your file association executes your .exe directly, the ClickOnce automatic updates will not work because the update info is stored in the Start Menu shortcut, not with the installed application files.

That is a different problem than the question you asked, but to get around that, if the app starts up with the .exe directly, I programmatically locate the Start Menu shortcut to the ClickOnce app (.appref-ms extension), then restart the app using that path (instead of the .exe), pass it the original command-line arguments that were sent to your .exe, then when it restarts, I retrieve THOSE arguments using **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData**.

Comment: Any idea how to add an icon association with that as well?

Answer (score 1):

This happened when we increased the version number and published the app under a different sub folder.
For example

- Version 1.0 was published to `\\server\product\version 1.0\`
- Version 2.0 was published to `\\server\product\version 2.0\`

I followed the answer of @EvAlex, and a dialog was prompted and I clicked the "Details" button, which opened up a log file. In the log file, I noticed that the program tried to download from a path of a old version, the path it was looking for is still `\\server\product\version 1.0\`.

Then I realized it should be something in the registry.

I opened up `regedit`, and did a search for `product` (which is my product name), and found the path that the log error complained under a few keys like followings:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes.myext
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\MyProgId
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyProgId

I deleted those keys, and repeated the `Open With` action, the icon is back and it then worked like a charm.

So looks like the app was not cleanly uninstalled or there's bug of ClickOnce updating these keys for some unknown reasons.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>ClickOnce does not pass command line arguments the usual way, but through</strike>

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData
```

So in your application startup you will need to check weather it holds any strings and modify your startup-behavior accordingly.

This is because ClickOnce applications are started through the deployment manifest on the server and not through an .exe. Btw: Setting your file associations via Properties -> Publish -> Options -> File Associations should work fine.

**Edit:** (how I created my sample app)

- create windows forms app
- activate ClickOnce-security settings, select fully trusted application
- in ClickOnce options -> descriptions, set publisher, suite and product name
- in ClickOnce options -> file associations add a new extension
- publish the app, install the app, test weather it starts when opening a file (it does)

All settings not mentioned have not been touched ... that is all I have done!

Seems like that is exactly what you did - maybe try creating a simple test application and see if that works for you. As this answer does not really answer your question please let me know when you are done so I can delete it.

Comment: I don't see how this helps.  I appreciate the answer, but as I stated, Properties -> Publish -> Options -> File Associations does not work.  I also do handle the data passed through the AppDomain, which shouldn't (and doesn't) change anything.

Comment: Well, I created a test-app before posting this. Just a windows forms app, applied the ClickOnce settings you chose (offline, trusted app, and set the file association via options), then added the code above. It works for me. You are right though that it is not necessary to get the command line - I mixed this up because I also did need if for my past project. Nevertheless, my simple test project (as described) and its file associations do work. I will try again and create a project and let you know exactly what I did in a little while.

Comment: My application follows these steps, however it does not work for me.  That is very odd, no?

Answer (score 0):

I found Alan's post above most helpful. It worked as it was written for me on one of my computers, but on another it didn't quite get me there. I was hoping to just add a comment to his post, but Stack Overflow says I don't have the reputation points for that.

If you need it, hope you can still find it here.

I also had to remove a key like the following for each extension mapping:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppName.FileType.0
```

Adding this to Adam's removal of the other `.ext` keys fixed the problem on my other machine.